# Cómo traduces "legacy" dentro del contexto de tecnología?

Tags: traducción

La traducción literal hecha por software de la palabra `legacy` es `herencia`, pero me parece que es completamente erróneo.

`legacy system` se traduce perfectamente como `sistema antíguo`

Pero si quieres traducir la palabra `legacy` como `antíguo`, por sí sola, resulta muy impreciso.

Por ejemplo:

`account (legacy)` => `cuenta (antígua)`

Hay ambigüedad y podría ser interpretado como:

`es una cuenta vieja` en vez de `es una cuenta creada en el sistema viejo` (siendo que la cuenta ha sido creada recientemente)

Comment: How about "tradicional"?

Comment: How about "heredado/a"?

Comment: [Código heredado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_heredado).

Comment: `herencia` and its derivatives are never the right translation within the context of technology, only machines do that, we have to train them differently

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que un *legacy account* es una cuenta que se sigue manteniendo a pesar de venir de un sistema antiguo.  No tiene por qué ser antiguo, y es posible que existan cuentas no *legacy* que son más antiguas aún (en el caso de fusionar dos plataformas, por ejemplo).

Según Wikipedia (entre las entradas para *Legacy system* y *Legacy code*, la forma en castellano es *heredado*.  Es la solución que ha tenido el francés (*hérité*) y el italiano cuando este no opta por el inglés (*ereditato*).  El portugués, a su vez, prefiere *legado* que no me parece mal en español (y, de hecho, se usa).

Una búsqueda en Google demuestra que con varios términos relacionado al contexto informático *heredado* se usa 2-4x más que *legado* y mucho más (10x o más) que el anglicismo *legacy* (que también disfruta de algún desafortunado uso).  Pero ojo: es difícil a veces separar los resultados lusófonos o italianos de los castellanos.  Aún así, creo que consta bien los dos términos no solo prevalentes pero bien adecuados con respecto a la idea de algo antiguo que se sigue manteniendo a pesar de su antigüedad.

Por eso, puedes emplear bien **heredado** bien **legado** para traducir *legacy*, teniendo en cuenta que la primera es algo más usado que la segunda.

Comment: Muy buena información, amplia mi perspectiva. Sin embargo, en mi experiencia como ingeniero, usualmente me parece más util hacer uso de anglicismos cuando no es posible encontrar una traducción de alta precisión. Curiosamente, el orden de preferencia que tengo para la traducción es opuesto a los datos de popularidad que presentas. `legacy` > `legado` > `heredado`

Comment: @givense es posible que haya algunas interferencias en las búsquedas en Google precisamente porque en muchos casos es difícil descartar ocurrencias en idiomas hermanos o que no pertenecen al campo informático (algo ejemplificado por ejemplo en el caso de «sistema» que a veces habla de cosas legales aunque con el mismo significado / idea)